# Join 3 tables even when one may not have any data

Tags: sql

I am trying to write a basic SQL query, but can't quite get it to work.

I am trying to join 3 tables when 1 of the tables may not have a value.

```
    select 
          distinct(jobnumber), 
          name, 
          reference, 
          DescriptionOption
       from 
          Heading 
             join tracking 
                on heading.jobkeyid = tracking.jobkeyid 
             join Information 
                on Heading.jobkeyid = information.jobkeyid 
       Where 
              StageID < 199 
          and heading.DateInProduction > '2022-07-01 00:00:00.000' 
          and DescriptionOption IN ('Style FF', 'FF')
       order by 
          JobNumber desc
```

This is what I have done but if the tracking table doesn't have the requested data it doesn't show in the results.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN`....

Comment: It sounds like you could use a [good tutorial](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/sql-joins-tutorial/) on joins.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: also, best to always qualify table.column (or alias.column) since others dont know your table structures, especially with joins.  Which table is the "OPTIONAL" table that may NOT have a matching record?  Tracking or Information?  Which table for StageId, DescriptionOption, JobNumber.  Please EDIT the existing query and fully qualify.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between "INNER JOIN" and "OUTER JOIN"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join)

Comment: Hi DRapp, Sorry I am a complete novice. The Optional table is tracking, the tables are as follows: tracking.StageID, Information.DescriptionOption, Heading.JobNumber.

Comment: I hope this makes sense

Comment: Hi Barry, I must admit I did try Left Join after doing a bit of Research but it made no difference

Comment: Hi Stu, You are not wrong at all, I am not trained in Microsoft SQL, I am just limping along, thank you for the link

Comment: select 
          distinct(Heading.jobnumber), 
          Heading.name, 
          Heading.reference, 
          Information.DescriptionOption
       from 
          Heading 
             join tracking 
                on heading.jobkeyid=tracking.jobkeyid 
             join Information 
                on Heading.jobkeyid = information.jobkeyid 
       Where 
              Tracking.StageID < 199 
          and heading.DateInProduction > '2022-07-01 00:00:00.000' 
          and Information.DescriptionOption IN ('Style FF', 'FF')
       order by 
          Heading.JobNumber desc

Comment: Hi DRapp, Is this what you wanted me to do? I really appreciate your help.